# How to add Reply-To header in $woocommerce->mailer()

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, mailer, orders

I had a custom WooCommerce mailer function below for sending emails to customers as a notification of there purchase, but I got a requirement to add reply-to tag.

To describe in detail, customer has to get email(`$order->billing_email`) for the order notification from `store@mycompany.com` and need to append reply-to tag for `support@mycompany.com`.

What this does is that emails will be send from `store@mycompany.com`, but when customers hit reply when they want to ask us any questions, these replies will go to `support@mycompany.com`

Can any one help me how to change the `$mailer->send` function to achieve the requirement ?

```
function my_awesome_publication_notification($order_id, $checkout=null) {
   global $woocommerce;
   $order = new WC_Order( $order_id );
   if($order->status === 'completed' ) {
      // Create a mailer
      $mailer = $woocommerce->mailer();

      $message_body = __( 'Hello world!!!' );

      $message = $mailer->wrap_message(
        // Message head and message body.
        sprintf( __( 'Order %s received' ), $order->get_order_number() ), $message_body );


      // Client email, email subject and message.
     $mailer->send( $order->billing_email, sprintf( __( 'Order %s received' ), $order->get_order_number() ), $message );
     }

   }
}
```

Comment: Try to check what is inside `get_headers()` I think your email is hidden there. And if so, maybe this can be useful: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/183206/adding-reply-to-in-the-email#answer-183224

Comment: Have you tried filtering [`woocommerce_email_headers`](https://github.com/woothemes/woocommerce/blob/f8db1c403fd81b18958b675421ee9fc012fa6551/includes/emails/class-wc-email.php#L281)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Added Compatibility for Woocommerce 3+

When looking at [Class WC_Email](https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/class-WC_Email.html) at the send() function you have:

```
send( string $to, string $subject, string $message, string $headers, string $attachments )
```

Transposing this to your code, $headers could be used this way:

```
function my_awesome_publication_notification($order_id, $checkout=null) {
    global $woocommerce;

    // Get order object.
    $order = new WC_Order( $order_id );

    $order_status = method_exists( $order, 'get_status' ) ? $order->get_status() : $order->status;

    if( $order_status === 'completed' ) {

        // Create a mailer
        $mailer = $woocommerce->mailer();

        $message_body = __( 'Hello world!!!' );

        // Message head and message body.
        $message = $mailer->wrap_message( sprintf( __( 'Order %s received' ), $order->get_order_number() ), $message_body );

        // Here is your header
        $reply_to_email = 'support@mycompany.com';
        $headers = array( sprintf( 'Reply-To: %s', $reply_to_email ) );
        // Or instead, try this in case:
        // $headers = 'Reply-To: ' . $reply_to_email . '\r\n';

        // Client email, email subject and message (+ header "reply to").
        $mailer->send( $order->billing_email, sprintf( __( 'Order %s received' ), $order->get_order_number() ), $message, $headers );
    }
}
```

This should work. Please take a look to last reference code, as it's very similar to yours…

References:

- [Class WC_Email](https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/class-WC_Email.html)
- [WooCommerce - Send email when the order status change](https://gist.github.com/claudiosmweb/6071237) *(very similar interesting code)*